# How to solve this dll missing problen in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I clone the project from git, directly using visual studio 2019.

Following error I'm getting :
*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Ragnar, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. WebTorrentX*
[image: Screent shot of my VS 2019]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the options, try to use x64 or x32 in configuration menu.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried both ways. but It doesn't work

Comment: Still the same error message? x86 should be the one to use I guess.